# Unable to see text in the dropdown list

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

So in my project I am using react for the frontend and django for the backend. I have the following model

```
class Role(models.Model):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('Recruiter', 'Recruiter'),
        ('Manager', 'Manager'),
        ('Business Development Partner', 'Business Development Partner'),
        ('Business Development Partner Manager', 'Business Development Partner Manager'),
        ('Account Manager', 'Account Manager'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have created the following view to get the role choices I have defined to the frontend

```
@csrf_exempt
def role_choices(request):
    roles = [role[1] for role in Role.ROLE_CHOICES]
    return JsonResponse(roles, safe=False)
```

And this is the endpoint I created for it

```
path('roles/', role_choices, name='roles_list'),
```

Now in my frontend, I have a form, with one of the field being a role, which when clicked should show a dropdown list populated with the role choices (only pasting the required code here)

```
<h2>Role</h2>
        <label>
          Select Role:
          <select
            name="role"
            value={userData.role}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          >
            <option value="">Select</option>
            {roleOptions.map(role => (
              <option key={role.id} value={role.role}>
                {role.role}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </label>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

But I dont see the role options on the webpage

[image]

I have logged the response I get when calling the endpoint and I see the role options being fetched[image]

The below code shows how I am setting the role options on the webpage

```
const [roleOptions, setRoleOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch role options from backend when component mounts
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/roles/')
    .then(response => {
      // Check if response data is an array
      if (Array.isArray(response.data)) {
        setRoleOptions(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      } else {
        console.error('Invalid response data:', response.data);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching roles:', error);
    });
}, []);
```

I dont why I am not able to see the role choices on the webpage, even after I get the correct response from the endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no `id` or `role`, you just returned a list of strings. You should wrap these in dictionaries, like:

```
@csrf_exempt
def role_choices(request):
    roles = [{'id': key, 'role': role} for key, role in Role.ROLE_CHOICES]
    return JsonResponse(roles, safe=False)
```

It however has not really an "id" or at least it is not an id of a model.

---

> **Note**: In 2008, [Phil Haack discovered a way to obtain data from the outer JSON array](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/).
> While most browser have implemented countermeasures, it is still better to use a
> JSON object as "envelope" of the data. That is why a
> [**`JsonResponse`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)
> by default does not allow something else than a `dict` as outer object. It might
> thus better to wrap the data in a dictionary and keep `safe=True` on `True`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I have updated my view as follows so that I can update the role for the given user, but it throws me 404 error.
def submit_user_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        role_id = data.get('role')
        role = get_object_or_404(Role, pk=role_id)
        user_data = UserData.objects.create(
            #omitted as it is same
            role=role,  # Assign the role object
        )
       #omitted the rest as it same

Comment: @RevanthKumarPerla: But based on both the question and the comment, I seems you have some misunderstanding what `choices` means: choices does *not* mean it will create `Role` objects, there are no `Role` records at all, you restrict the value for the roles so when people would *create* a role, they can only pick one of these, that does not mean these exist in the first plac.e

Comment: Ok I undertand that. So how I do I restrict the user with the choice, and also create role object linked to that user. I need the roles to be linked with the user so that I can display dashboards according to the role assigned to them